# Binding styles from ResourceDictionary to usercontrols

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, resourcedictionary

I'm new to wpf so I'm looking for a solution and an explanation of why my attempted solution is not working.

Here's my case.
I have several UserControls. In each of them I apply the following style:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource Centratura}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Property1.IsAbilitato}" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

based on a style defined in a resource dictionary. **And it works fine**.
But note that for every UserControl, the previous code is identical, except for the binding property, that will be Property1.IsAbilitato, Property2.IsAbilitato, Property3.IsAbilitato...

But this is a code duplication I don't like. I was wondering how to put the style in the resource dictionary and apply the proper binding later in each usercontrol.

I tried using the Tag property like what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598200/datatrigger-binding-in-wpf-style), in this way:

In my user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="whatever"
    ...
    Tag="{Binding Property1.IsAbilitato}"
    ...>
```

and in the resourcedictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

but it doesn't work. Suggestions? Other solutions? (I'm using MVVM, if it's relevant).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you applied that resource file to your app.xaml ?

Comment: Yes, I did. It works for other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the Tag to the TextBox itself:

```
<TextBox Tag="{Binding Property1.IsAbilitato}"/>
```

if you want the following to work:

```
 <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

But if you want to add it to the UserControl and want all TextBox's to be applied to then you have to change it to:

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```